# Android : parse the json within json object in java

Tags: android, json

I have the json like this..

```
 {"source":[{"id":"22","name":"xyz"},{"id":"23","name":"ghj"},
 {"id":"24","name":"tuv"}]}
```

I've to get the value of "id" and "name". How to do that..

I've tried a lot. But can't get the best solution how to do this.

thanks for the help

Comment: You need to use SimpleAdapter with listview

Comment: use google gson: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 1):

You want to use following code....

```
 JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                sourceArray = jObject.getJSONArray("source");
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    name[i] = sourceArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").toString();
                    id[i] = sourceArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id");
                }
```

responseBody is your actual JSON String.
Reply if you have any doubts.